# Applying Functions to Filtered Rows in R

Tags: r

I have a long data set where each row is a state's income tax rate for that year. Here are a few rows as an example:

```
State   statefip year  TopRate
  <chr>      <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>
1 Alabama        1 2018     0.05
2 Alabama        1 2017     0.05
3 Alabama        1 2016     0.05
4 Alabama        1 2015     0.05
5 Alabama        1 2014     0.05
6 Alabama        1 2013     0.05
7 Alabama        1 2012     0.05
8 Alabama        1 2011     0.05
9 Alabama        1 2010     0.05
10 Alaska         2 2018     0
```

I would like to create an additional column that is a quantile (.5, .75, .80.. and so on) for each year. So, the .5 (median) column would have the median tax rate for all states in the year 2018 and so on for each year. To clarify, every observation for a given state in the year 2018 would have the same tax rate for the .5 but they would change for each year. While this may seem weird, it will help me when I have to merge this data with other data I have later. Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: here's what I want..

```
State   statefip year  TopRate median     q3    q80    q85    q90 jenkb$jenkb
   <chr>      <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>       <int>
 1 Alabama        1 2018     0.05 0.0575 0.0700 0.074  0.0888 0.0897           0
 2 Alabama        1 2017     0.05 0.0575 0.0700 0.074  0.0854 0.0895           0
 3 Alabama        1 2016     0.05 0.0575 0.0700 0.074  0.0854 0.0895           0
 4 Alabama        1 2015     0.05 0.0575 0.0700 0.074  0.0888 0.0897           0
 5 Alabama        1 2014     0.05 0.058  0.07   0.0765 0.0888 0.0897           0
 6 Alabama        1 2013     0.05 0.0599 0.072  0.0775 0.0839 0.0895           0
 7 Alabama        1 2012     0.05 0.06   0.072  0.0775 0.0866 0.0895           0
 8 Alabama        1 2011     0.05 0.06   0.0738 0.078  0.085  0.0897           0
 9 Alabama        1 2010     0.05 0.06   0.0738 0.078  0.0872 0.0897           1
10 Alaska         2 2018     0    0.0575 0.0700 0.074  0.0888 0.0897           0
# ... with 449 more rows
```

Except I want the JenkB column to be a 1 for every year the state fits into the second bucket for the Jenks break for that given year.

```
taxlong %>%
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(median = quantile(TopRate, .5)) %>%
  mutate(q3 = quantile(TopRate, .75)) %>%
  mutate(q80 = quantile(TopRate, .80)) %>%
  mutate(q85 = quantile(TopRate, .85)) %>%
  mutate(q90 = quantile(TopRate, .90)) #%>%
  #mutate(jenkb = as.integer((TopRate > 0.0323 & year == 2018 | 2017 | 2015) | (TopRate > 0.0375 & year == 2016) | (TopRate > 0.034 & year == 2014 | 2013 | 2012 | 2011 | 2010)))
```

This code didn't work

Comment: All the values seems to be 0.05.  You may try `df1 %>% group_by(State, statefip, year) %>% mutate(new = cut(TopRate, breaks = c(-Inf, quantile(TopRate), Inf)))`

Comment: So, you want a quantile per year and a quantile per state?

Comment: Can you share the expected output for the example shared?

Comment: @Ronak Shah I edited the original post to add the expected output

Comment: What do you mean by second bucket? and which are these values? `0.0323`, `0.0375` etc?

Comment: For each year there is a different tax rate that would put you in the higher bucket. For many of the years those values are the same, for 2018, 2017 and 2015 that value is 0.0323. For 2016 it's 0.0375 and for the rest of the years it's 0.034

Comment: Perhaps, you were looking for `mutate(jenkb = as.integer(TopRate > 0.0323 & year %in% c(2018,2017,2015) |  (TopRate > 0.0375 & year == 2016) | (TopRate > 0.034 & year %in% 2010:2014)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `quantile` with `cut` to create a column after grouping by the group columns 'year'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by( year) %>% 
    mutate(new = cut(TopRate, breaks = c(-Inf, quantile(TopRate, 
            probs = c(.5, .75, .8) ), Inf)))
```

If we wanted to create new columns with `quantile` values (values will be repeated for each row), place it in a `list` and then `unnest` it to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(year) %>%
   mutate(new = list(quantile(TopRate, probs = c(.5, .75, .8)))) %>% 
   unnest_wider(c(new))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, new := cut(TopRate, breaks = c(-Inf, quantile(TopRate, probs = c(.5, .75, .8)), Inf)), .( year)]
```

Comment: That works, except I don't want them grouped by state and statefip just year (so all states in 2018 have the same median value for 2018). But now my median value is a range from -inf to the median value ``` State   statefip year  TopRate new          
   <chr>      <dbl> <fct>   <dbl> <fct>        
 1 Alabama        1 2018     0.05 (-Inf,0.0575]

Comment: @MattSimonson updated the post by changing the grouping column

Comment: is there an easy way to get it so the value is just the median not a range?

Comment: I am going to have a separate column for each percentile

Comment: @MattSimonson If you just want to have two groups, you don't need `cut` i.e. `mutate(new = as.integer(TopRate >= median(TopRate, na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: @MattSimonson If you use `mutate`, that values will be repeated.  Do you need `summarise`

Comment: @MattSimonson What I meant is `library(tidyr);df1 %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(new = list(quantile(TopRate, probs = c(.5, .75, .8)))) %>% unnest_wider(c(new))`

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused by your question, however, I'm not sure how to get this back into my dataset.

Comment: @MattSimonson I see your post.  You are creating a column with `mutate`.  In my previous comment, I am summariseing.  If you want to create multple columns, just replace `summarise` with `mtuate` i.e. `df1 %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(new = list(quantile(TopRate, probs = c(.5, .75, .8)))) %>% unnest_wider(c(new))`

Comment: I have another related problem. Now I would like to add a column where if the state's tax rate for that year is greater than a certain value (determined by the Jenks-fisher natural break) then the value will be 1 and 0 if otherwise. For example, based on the 2018 distribution of taxes and two different categories (high-tax and low-tax) the cut off is 0.0323. Ideally, I could calculate the value by year and then place the 1 or 0.

Comment: @MattSimonson that is very easy `mutate(new = list(quantile(TopRate, probs = c(.5, .75, .8))), flag = +(TopRate > 0.0323)) %>% unnest_wider(c(new))` the 'flag' column can be created outside the group as well (as it is more efficient)

Comment: what if I don't know what the cutoff value would be for each given year? So the break is 0.0323 for the year 2018 but it's a different value for 2017 and so on.. do I just need to find that value for each year first?

Comment: I tried this code mutate(jenkb = as.integer((TopRate > 0.0323 & year == 2018 | 2017 | 2015) | (TopRate > 0.0375 & year == 2016) | (TopRate > 0.034 & year == 2014 | 2013 | 2012 | 2011 | 2010))) but it didn't work. Everything is listed as 1 even for Alaska which is a 0 for every year

Comment: @MattSimonson I would create a key/val dataset and join that `keydat <- data.frame(year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014), thresh = c(0.034, 0.035, 0.037, 0.034, 0.040)); left_join(df1, keyda) %>% mutate(jenkb = as.integer(TopRate > thresh))`

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your help.

```
taxlong %>%
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(median = quantile(TopRate, .5))
```

works perfectly, I'll just repeat the process for each of the quantiles I need. I need to keep the values for my later analysis.